# Run task multiple times in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to run my task multiple times in my sbt build.

```
lazy val sampleTask = taskKey[Unit]("A sample task.")

val dynamic = Def.taskDyn {
    println("Called dynamic")
    Def.task {
      println("Executing dynamic task")
    }
}

lazy val library = (project in file("library")).
settings(
 sampleTask := {
   for (i <- (1 until 4)) {
     println(s"Loop $i")
     val num = dynamic.value
   }
 }
)
```

SBT by default caches execution of task and as result I get:

```
Called dynamic
Executing dynamic task
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3
```

I want to run dynamic task every time it is called, so I get:

```
Called dynamic
Executing dynamic task
Loop 1
Called dynamic
Executing dynamic task
Loop 2
Called dynamic
Executing dynamic task
Loop 3
```

Is it possible to force sbt to run the same task many times in one build?

Comment: do you want to run dynamic task and all its dependency every time or only dynamic task?

Comment: I want to run tests N times, after every test run copy test result to separate folder. After running tests N times I will process all results to find flaky tests.
So, I want to run task with its dependencies every time.

Comment: I think you will need to write a command instead of a task. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @seth-tisue for comment. I have created command and I'm calling task multiple times: https://github.com/otrebski/sbt-flaky/commit/308a5dd34afbcbfcc4da9a71ec16b20e0c168ec0#diff-fba3577a701d9ead931278034fe240a6

```
def flaky = Command("flaky")(parser) {(state,args) =>
  val taskKey = Keys.test in Test
  for (i <- (1 to count)) {
    println(s"Running tests: $i")
    Project.runTask(taskKey, state)
  }
}
```